# Outlook 2007 sent item says message not sent, even though its been sent

Tags: microsoft-outlook, google-workspace

I have a funny problem with my outlook sent items.

Im using outlook 2007 for Goolge Apps account. Some messages on the sent items say "Message has not been sent" but are actually sent and I even got response from the other end. This doesn't happen to all the messages, but randomly ! When I open those message on the sent items, it comes up as a new message with send option, I'm confused !!!

The sent items have a different icon for these messages which has the error. I just cant figure out this, please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google has [released a new version of Google Apps Sync](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google%20Apps/thread?tid=3abd102e76828a40&hl=en) that should resolve the issue. Otherwise I would suggest contacting their support (assuming Google Apps for Business).